# Unity app crashes with Firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I added the Firebase SDK to my Unity game. Unity compiles fine but when I start the game on my Android device it crashed immediately before showing the splash screen.

Logcat is giving me the error below. I've also added the gradle file that I'm using. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Here's the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.puzzletime.jigsaw, PID: 10617
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbp;
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6335)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5866)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.puzzletime.jigsaw-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.puzzletime.jigsaw-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.puzzletime.jigsaw-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6335) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5927) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5866) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'AdinCube-Unity-606ebe', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'NativeGallery', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'ShortcutBadger-1.1.5', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'adcolony-3.2.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'admob-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'amazon-dex-5.8.1.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'applovin-7.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'appnext-core-dex-1.7.7', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'appnext-dex-1.7.7', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'appnext-sdk-dex-1.7.7', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'chartboost-dex-7.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'doubleclick-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'exoplayer-r2.0.3', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-4.26.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-unity-4.2.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-app-unity-4.2.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-common-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-common-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-core-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-iid-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-iid-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mobile-native-popups', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mopub-4.14.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mopub-banner-4.14.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mopub-base-4.14.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mopub-interstitial-4.14.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'mopub-rewardedvideo-4.14.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-drive-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-games-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gass-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gass-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gcm-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gcm-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-iid-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-iid-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-nearby-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'recyclerview-v7-25.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'unity-2.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'utnotifications', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'vungle-5.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
    compile project(':MainLibProj')
    compile project(':UTNotificationsRes')
    compile project(':localizedappnamelib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
        applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
            multiDexEnabled true    
    }

    dexOptions {
          javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
      }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Build Apk. and then install it in device.

Comment: This doesn't work since it's the same as building it in Unity and deploying it to the device.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue now (2019), have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a conflict between google-play services versions,

Have you tried updating your support-* .aar files ?

Maybe it's related to multi-dex ?

I recently had an issue with multi-dex on Android 4.x. Some lib where present but not found when running.
See this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Yes I tried. I'm using the jar resolver and when installing the Firebase SDK it downloads all the latest libraries.

Comment: Is your device on Android 4.x ?

Comment: No, it's on Android 7. I've also tried it on an Android 6 device. Doesn't make any difference. Also updated the buildToolsVersion to match the targetSdkVersion. Problem still remains.